# Correspondence between Feynman diagrams in the $n$-point correlation function expansions for 2 different cutoffs

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

My understanding of QFT is quite elementary. I'm reading through Kevin Costello's book on Renormalization and effective field theory, which is based on Wilsonian low energy theory.

The integral for an $n$-point function can be made to converge by imposing a (say length scale) cutoff (regulator), and this $n$-point function should be independent of the choice of cutoff.

Q. Now, let's fixate on just one diagram in the $n$-point function at one scale ($l$). Is it possible to determine/draw all the diagrams in some other scale (larger length scale $L$) of the same $n$-point function, whose sum of weights is equal to the weight of this diagram?

Please correct me if I've used any incorrect terms/concepts or have been ambiguous with my question.